# How to remove duplicates correct?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have a **MySQL** chart table like this : PRIMARY KEY(ID), Name, Value, Date

I need to remove duplicates if "Name AND Value AND Date" are the same as existing row.
I have beneath a solution i found while ago and which worked (not 100%), but I don't understand the command in it's total because I'm only into BASIC MySQL... Can somebody explain me a little further...

definitely what is the x at the end ???

```
$delDups = "delete from chart where id not in (select * from (select min(id) from chart n group by value) x)";

mysql_query($delDups);
```

Comment: This is a rather complicated query with two subqueries. The x in the end is an alias for the inner-most subquery, IIRC MySQL forces you to give aliases to subqueries under certain conditions even if you wouldn't need them.

Comment: Does MySQL allow this query? I didn't think it allowed `UPDATE` or `DELETE` to use `WHERE IN (subquery)` when the subquery references the same table you're deleting from? I usually have to rewrite things like this using `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Okay thanks already... do you know how to change the query so that if Name AND Value AND Date are equal to an exising row to just delete the duplicate ?

Comment: yes it works like this but it only doesn't remove the rows correct

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you could do it simpler, like this:

```
$delDups = "delete from chart where id not in (select min(id) from chart n group by value)";
```

In the subquery you are saing:
" Hey, take all the values and find the minimun id for the group of values"

So, imagine the result of the subquery as a list, like "(12, 13, 200)".. the NOT IN operator will take that list and use it to filter the result of the upper query and say "Give me all the results, less the ones where id is in this list"

I'm not sure if I explained it as expected...

Comment: There's no need for the `n` alias.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an unique key for all 3 columns:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_unic UNIQUE (Name, Value, Date)
```

As to that x,mysql permit aliases,essentially name shortcuts for convenience.

Comment: I believe you could only do this after removing the duplicates, though it would probably be a useful addition to the OP's schema.

Comment: Nope it will remove duplicates as you add it.

Comment: Huh, I'm more of a Postgres guy, but wouldn't MySQL complain unless you put a `IGNORE` clause in there?

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote will almost work, you just want to add the `name` and `date` to the `GROUP BY` clause.  Something like this should do.

```
DELETE FROM chart
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(id)
  FROM chart
  GROUP BY name, value, date)
```

The `DELETE FROM` says you want to be deleting rows from a table.  The `WHERE` clause says which rows you actually want to delete (missing it out will remove everything).  The sub-query in the brackets will look through every combination of `name`, `value` and `date` and give you one `id` back from each combination.  Putting it all together, the `DELETE` should now drop every row whose `id` isn't the smallest for each group.

Hope that helps!